# React-Hook-Form and appending data in server action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've created a form that has user input along with an image that will get uploaded to cloudinary. Using RHF I've registered all of my inputs and im using the handleSubmit() function. Im calling a function called submitFormAction. Id like to validate the photo before saving it to my DB. For some reason the only way I can modify formData is if I save the picture as a separate state value.

here's my code:

```
const submitFormAction =  async (data) => {

    console.log(data)

    console.log(data.picture?.[0])  <---- I can see the image data :) 
    const image = data.picture?.[0]

    if (!image) return

    const formData = new FormData();

    console.log(formData) 

    formData.append("file", image);
    formData.append(
      "api_key",
      process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_API_KEY as string
    );
    formData.append("signature", signature);
    formData.append("timestamp", timestamp);
    formData.append("folder", "daycareApp");

    console.log(formData)   <----- this always just returns a blank FormData :(
```

any pointers woudld be much appreciated !

Comment: You cannot print a `FormData`'s content like that, you'll have to iterate through it and print each key - value pair.

Comment: oh wow thanks @Titus I can see the formData if I do this:  ```for (const pair of formData.entries()) {
  const [key, value] = pair;
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`); 
}```